# Angular ui routers nested ui-views showing blank

Tags: angularjs

I've looked through the Stackoverflow but yet to find a solution. 
I have one top page with a ui-view then a works page that has a second ui-view. I added `ui-view="portfolio"` then linked it in my main js file, but nothing.

app.js

```
        'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'app/about/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .state('work', {
        url: '/work/:workId',
        views: {
        'portfolio@work': {
          templateUrl: 'app/work/work.html',
          controller: 'WorkCtrl'
          }
        }
      });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    });

    app.run(['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http) {
      $http.get('projects/projects.json').success(function(data) {

    function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
      for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x){}
        return o;
    }

    $rootScope.allWorks = shuffle(data);
    });
    }]);
```

Work controller

```
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp');

    app.controller('WorkCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $location) {

        if (!$stateParams.workId) {
            $location.path('/');
        }

        $http.get('projects/' + $stateParams.workId + '.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.work = data;
            $scope.pageClass = 'page-work'; // only use to add class for ui view

            //function for next previous

            var currentWorkIndex;
            var l = $scope.allWorks.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                if ($scope.allWorks[i].id === $stateParams.workId) {
                    currentWorkIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var prevWorkIndex = (currentWorkIndex !== 0) ? (currentWorkIndex - 1) : (l - 1);
            var nextWorkIndex = (currentWorkIndex !== l - 1) ? (currentWorkIndex + 1) : (0);
            $scope.prevWork = $scope.allWorks[prevWorkIndex].id;
            $scope.nextWork = $scope.allWorks[nextWorkIndex].id;


        });

    }]);
```

main Controller

```
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp');

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-home';

    }]);
```

Work html

```
    <div class="work {{work.class}}" data-loading="{{1}}" ui-view="portfolio">

      <section class="top">

        <img src="/assets/images/placeholder.png" ng-src="{{work.img.top}}" alt="{{work.sub}}">

        <hgroup>
          <h3>{{work.title}}</h3>
          <h5>{{work.sub}}</h5>
        </hgroup>

      </section>

      <article>
        <div class="col1">
          <h5>Background</h5>
          <p>{{work.bg}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <h5>Involvement</h5>
          <p>{{work.role}}</p>
          <h5>Visit</h5>
          <a href="{{work.url}}" target="_blank">{{work.url}}</a>
        </div>
      </article>

      <section class="photos">
        <img src="/assets/images/placeholder.png" ng-src="{{work.img.left}}" alt="{{work.sub}}">
        <img src="/assets/images/placeholder.png" ng-src="{{work.img.right}}" alt="{{work.sub}}">
      </section>

      <section class="ui">
        <img src="/assets/images/placeholder.png" ng-src="{{work.img.ui}}" alt="{{work.sub}}">
      </section>

      <footer>
        <a ui-sref="work({workId:prevWork})"><span class="icon-chevron-l"></span><p>Previous</p></a>
        <a href="/#/"><span class="icon-close-line"></span></a>
        <a ui-sref="work({workId:nextWork})"><p>Next</p><span class="icon-chevron-r"></span></a>
      </footer>

    </div>
```

Here is a plunkr. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/KyiynhLsjjKSp7dxGtYT?p=preview

Any tips, or advice would go a long way to solving my problem. Most tutorials only deal with a basic concept, but my problem is a little more complex.

Comment: app.js line 30 `$http.get('projects/projects.json')` there is no project.json in the plunkr files. Also ngAnimate, ngCookie files are not been called in index.html although you added them to `app.js` angular.module('myApp'

Comment: cheekybastard, sorry I was a little busy when making my plunkr and missed out key scripts and files. It should be all there now. The main focus of my question is nesting ui-view in my work partial to return data. At the moment in my application it doesn't.

Comment: I would suggest in the future your main focus should always be the console. With JS if something isn't working your first response should be F12 (open console), then F5 (refresh), then look at the error msgs. That plunkr still has basic project config errors, JS files missing from the index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/03D1dvCy1jIz5zCdCCWY) updated example.

Firstly, you misused ui-sref:

```
<a ui-sref="work.details({workId: work.id})">
```

`work.details` is a state and object in parentheses is data passed to the state resolved by its keys as state's url parameter placeholders (in short: `workId` key in object translates to `:workId` in url).

Secondly, I fixed a little bit your example by removing some irrelevant dependencies.

Last but not least, the states definition is now as the following:

```
  .state('work', {
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view="portfolio"></div>'
  })
  .state('work.details', {
    url: '/work/:workId',
    views: {
    'portfolio@work': {
      templateUrl: 'work.html',
      controller: 'WorkCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

Please refer to the [documentation on Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) for better understanding of this subject.

Comment: Top marks to you Xeon - this is exactly the type of explanation I needed. Many thanks, a great start to my weekend :)   I'll now go away and study the documentation on Multiple Named Views.